# Datepicker validation using Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, formik

I have created a date picker using `formik` and I have to do the validation using `Yup`. 
**Ex:** If my age is `18` by comparing it to the current date and if I select a date from the `date picker` `more than 18`, then it should give me a message my age is `less than 18`

Comment: why dont you provide some code example?

Comment: Dear @SamliPrajapati, I made your code more readable, Bolding all of the question's description make your content bad to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    const YourSettingSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  dateOfBirth: Yup.string()
    .nullable()
    .test('Date of Birth', 'Should be greather than 18', function(value) {
      return moment().diff(moment(value), 'years') >= 18;
    }),
});
```